# How to enter time variable into a tvLM() model?

Tags: r, regression, time-varying-covariate

I would like to know if the effect of a predictor varies over time.

So for example if the effect of "pred" on "dv" changes over the course of the "time" variable.

```
library(data.table)
library(tvReg)

time <- rep(1:100, 100)
dv <- rnorm(1000)
pred <- rnorm(1000)

d <- data.table(time, dv, pred)
```

I've heard of the tvReg package, and I assume the function I want is the `tvLM()`, but I can't figure out how to enter time into the model?

```
tvlm.fit <- tvLM(dv ~ pred, data = d)
```

Comment: The implementation assumes that observations are taken at regular intervals and the data frame is ordered by time.

Comment: @dipetkov Thanks!